# Meaning of module's instances in /proc/modules

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

I have used `cat /proc/modules` to list the modules details.

Below a module shows as 4 instances are present:

```
poe_isr 3046 4 - Live 0xc37e1000 (O)
```

What does it mean? How do I see where these instances are being used?

Next module is showing as 0 instances and Live:

```
adcmods 1565 0 - Live 0xc37dd000 (P)
```

What does it mean? The module is not loaded but still Live?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why some descriptions (like [this one](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/centos_linux_guides/centos_linux_reference_guide/s1-proc-topfiles.html)) name the third column of `/proc/modules` output as a "number of instances", but this is actually a module's **reference count**.

If a module has a positive (non-zero) reference count, then it cannot be unloaded with `/sbin/rmmod` (the command prints "ERROR: Module X is in use").

If some module's references are obtained by other *modules*, then a comma-separated list of these modules is printed as 4th column (instead of `-` character).

If the module's reference is obtained by non-module "objects", one should use other methods for listing these objects. E.g. a filesystem module is normally referenced by the filesystem's *mounts*, so one needs to check output of `/usr/bin/mount`.

Comment: The answer is way clearer than [this one](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-modules.html)

Comment: What about having `-1` in that third column?

Comment: Can a module have a reference module that references the first module? Essentially a circular reference between 2 modules

Comment: @Nanyo: No, circular dependencies between modules are not allowed.