# Does /proc/modules only list kernel modules that are correctly loaded?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

The red hat documentation regarding this file is vague. At first, it states that:

> This file displays a list of all modules loaded into the kernel

But then later in the doc, it says:

> The third column lists how many instances of the module are currently
> loaded. A value of zero represents an unloaded module.

So my questions are:

1. If the third value for a module is 0, does this mean that it is no longer loaded in the kernel right now? If so, then why do all of them still have a kernel address?
2. If /proc/modules only shows the currently loaded kernel modules, how can I find the list of all the kernel modules that will get loaded automatically after boot?

Comment: If it says "Live" and there is an address, then the module is loaded.  The 3rd number is the module refcnt.  Any non-zero number will prevent the module from being unloaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of module's instances in /proc/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645859/meaning-of-modules-instances-in-proc-modules)

Comment: Concerning the "list of all the kernel modules that will get loaded automatically after boot", see [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527168/kernel-modules-loaded-when-boot) on Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

According to [/kernel/module/procfs.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/module/procfs.c) this third value is not the number of instances, but the reference count of the module (`module_refcount`).

If a module has a reference count > 0 than it can't be unload safely (other modules expect it to be there), but if the reference count is 0 the module can be unloaded, but it's still loaded as of now.

Don't know why this documentation got it wrong.

2.
A systemd service called `systemd-modules-load.service` loads modules at boot time. [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html) is some documentation that shows how it works and where to look.
However, there is a different service for systems withoud systemd and I'm pretty  sure you have some other ways of loading a modules.